# Listing only CCRC Views

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

Can anyone think of a quick, easy and fullproof way of listing only ClearCase Remote Client views from UNIX?

ct lsview obviously lists all the views, and you could search by looking at the Properties: section if you run a **ct lsview -properties -full** (gives you *Properties: snapshot webview readwrite*) then use a regex or something, but I'd be worried that someone calls their view 'webview' or something.

Has anyone got a foolproof way? Am I missing a flag or something? If only there was -fmt on lsview :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex detecting 'webview readwrite' should be good enough.

But even simpler, our CCRC server runs into its own ClearCase region (for instance 'web').

So in our case: "listing only ClearCase Remote Client views from UNIX" ?

```
ct lsview -reg web
```